# Is there a way to upload a big file from a direct download link to Google Drive without having to download it to the local machine first?

Tags: python, node.js, google-drive-api, ftp, file-transfer

Is transferring a file from a link to Google Drive using a custom script or programming solution feasible? I have a link which when clicked downloads a file. I want to transfer the file to drive without ever downloading it on my local machine.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, will this information be useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/DownloadLargeFilesByUrl

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Node.js:

The `media.body` parameter of the Google [`drive.files.create`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/create) method is a writable stream, into which you can pipe the response of the download request:

```js
var media = {
  mimeType: "...",
  body: new stream.PassThrough()
};
drive.files.create({
  requestBody: {name: "..."},
  media
}).then(function({data}) {
  https.get("download_link")
  .on("response", function(r) {
    r.pipe(media.body);
  });
});
```